# spring zuul route connection reset

Tags: spring, connection, router, netflix-zuul, netflix

I have my API gateway and all my microservices up and running in cloud foundry, and here's my configuration for the API gateway:

```
zuul.add-proxy-headers=true

zuul.routes.myservice.path=/ptp/myService/**
zuul.routes.myservice.url=${CLIENT_BASE_URL:http://localhost:8877/}/myservice
zuul.routes.myservice.sensitiveHeaders=

zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=60000
# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)   hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=60000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=60000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
```

The problem is that when I try to reach out to my microservice the first time after being idle for some time, I see a connection reset error logged into the API gateway.  I don't see anything logged in my client service.

But the same call is successful if I refresh my browser, or if I'm calling the service again.